# JavaFX image path for style

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently trying to make a custom button using JavaFX. I have defined 2 styles that contain 2 different images for 2 button states(Pressed and Free). I'm using Intellij Idea and when defining the paths it shows no error's, but the button doesn't show up. Its just transparent, but I can click it. I have tried specified different paths, but haven't gotten any result. Here is the code where I define the styles and my file tree. Thanks!

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {
    private final String FONT_PATH = "src/Resources/GUI/pixelFont.ttf";

    private final String BUTTON_PRESSED_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: transparent;" +
            " -fx-background-image: url('../../Resources/GUI/Buttondown.png');";
    private final String BUTTON_FREE_STYLE = "-fx-background-color: transparent;" +
            " -fx-background-image: url('../../Resources/GUI/Buttonup.png');";

    public CustomButton(String text) {
        setFont();
        setPrefWidth(180);
        setPrefHeight(53);
        setText(text);
        setStyle(BUTTON_PRESSED_STYLE);
        initButtonListeners();
    }
}
```

[File tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88Ba.png)

Comment: Have you checked if the files exist, for example, `Boolean exists = new File("../../Resources/GUI/Buttonup.png").exists();`, if it doesn't, then are you sure that it is not an inner class resource rather than a resource in an external folder?

Comment: The file indeed exists, I am able to successfully make and display an ImageView containing this image.

Comment: @kleopatra Could you please tell me where my naming is wrong? Because according to this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/amp/ my naming is correct.

Comment: the package name should be lowercase :)

Comment: Aha, thank you! Didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving all of the files into the pre-generated by Intellij Idea resources folder and then using that folder solved the issue.